Prove that $P(X_{n+m}=j|X_0=i_0,\dots, X_n=i)=p_{ij}^{(m)}$

Let $\{X_n\}$ satisfy the markov property. That is, $$P(X_{n+1}=j|X_0=i_0,\dots X_n=j)=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=j)=p_{ji}.$$
Then prove that $P(X_{n+m}=j|X_0=i_0,\dots, X_n=i)=p_{ij}^{(m)}$.

Intuitively, this problem is correct because we can treat $X_m$ to be the $0$th time and then $X_{n+m}$ becomes the $X_m$ time. But can someone give a formal proof?

I will sketch the proof of the case $m=2$; the general case is analogous.
Let $E_{n,i} = \{X_0=i_0, \ldots, X_n=i\}$.
\begin{align}
P(X_{n+2} = j \mid E_n)
&= \sum_{k} P(X_{n+2} = j, X_{n+1} = k \mid E_{n,i})
\\
&= \sum_{k} P(X_{n+2} = j \mid X_{n+1}=k, E_{n,i}) P(X_{n+1}=k \mid E_{n,i})
\\
&= \sum_{k} p_{k, j} p_{i, k}
\\
&= p^{(2)}_{ij}
\end{align}

what is $j'$? Do you mean $k$?

@Raheel Yes, fixed
